# How to exclude a specific version of a npm package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, vue-test-utils

My current config is:

```
 "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.25"
```

How can make it exclude a specific version of this package while still using the caret `^` rages?

The version which I want to exclude is `1.0.0-beta.31`, because this version currently broke my entire tests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the syntax is something like as follows:

```
"@vue/test-utils": ">1.0.0-beta.25 <1.0.0-beta.31 || ^1.0.0-beta.32"
```

You can find the rules for version resolution [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies).

Comment: With this syntax, when the `1.0.0-beta.32` come out, will I get the newest?

Comment: I just updated the answer to account for that situation.

Comment: you can use this https://semver.npmjs.com/ for test with syntax of @DigitalDrifter